# Have django ORM prepare sql, without executing

Tags: python, sql, django

I am doing a massive data conversion for data that will end up in a django managed database. For reasons of efficiency and politics, we need to fill the destination database with manually run mass INSERTS.

I would like to have my Django ORM prepare those statements, so I can write them to a file to be run later.

So I need somthing like this:

```
50000_or_so_Foos = [...]
sql_str = Foo.objects.bulk_create_sql(50000_or_so_Foos)
with file("pre_preped.sql", 'w') as f:
   f.write(sql_str)
```

Then we will pass pre_preped.sql to another department and they will play it into the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Is this actually going to save us any time?

**ADDED Question:** Should I be creating a csv for LOADDATA instead?

(I should note that in the real world, we have more than one model and way more than 50000 objects)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of any easy way to get the query from `bulk_create`, because it executes query when it is called, as opposed to somethign like `filter`ing where you can view the querysets `query` property.

As I was quickly scanning source code, it looks like you can manually build a query using the `sql` object, the same way django does in `bulk_create`.  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L917 can provide a blueprint on how to do that.